# How can use a where in firstOrCreate in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.3, eloquent

How can I use a code like this:

```
 $db = ModelName::firstOrCreate(['bot_id'=>10, 'bot_text'=>$botTxt->id])
->where('updated_at','<=', Carbon::today());
```

This is not working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ModelName::where('updated_at','<=', Carbon::today())
    ->firstOrCreate(['bot_id' => 10, 'bot_text' => $botTxt->id]);
```

Also, since `firstOrCreate()` uses the mass assignment feature, make sure you've defined the `$fillable` property in the `ModelName` class:

```
protected $fillable = ['bot_id', 'bot_text'];
```

Comment: I fixed anything not working, you can check `dd($db);`  every time `+exists: true` !!!! for example when I change `updated_at` to `2017-07-28 18:03:49` or `2017-07-25 18:03:49` in mySql data every time its true

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the condition in first param of the firstOrCreate method like that:

```
 $db = ModelName::firstOrCreate([
    ['updated_at','<=', Carbon::today()],
    'bot_id'=>10, 
    'bot_text'=>$botTxt->id
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $db = ModelName::firstOrCreate(
    [
        'updated_at' => Carbon::today()
    ],
    [
        'bot_id' => 10, 
        'bot_text' => $botTxt->id
    ]
 );
```